# Loop over a typescript object with null fields

Tags: angular, typescript, loops

Trying to loop on a object. Thing is the object a some fields defined to null, because i want to bypass firebase not accepting undefined values.
Here's the object :

In model.ts

```
export interface Page {
  id: string;
  titre: string;
  pres: string;
  st1: null;
  st2: null;
  st3: null;
  st4: null;
  st5: null;
  pa1: string;
  pa2: null;
  pa3: null;
  pa4: null;
  pa5: null;
  image1: null;
  image2: null;
  image3: null;
  lien: null;
  nomlien: null;
}
```

```
In component.ts : 
 page: Page = {
    id: '',
    titre: '',
    pres: '',
    st1: null,
    pa1: '',
    st2: null,
    st3: null,
    st4: null,
    st5: null,
    pa2: null,
    pa3: null,
    pa4: null,
    pa5: null,
    image1: null,
    image2: null,
    image3: null,
    lien: null,
    nomlien: null,
  };
```

I can make this working :

```
if (page.st1 === undefined || page.st1 === '') {
      page.st1 = null;
    }
```

But I would like to do this in a loop on this object, so I don't need 15 Ifs and my object can still be registered in Firebase.

I've tried foreach, for in, for of, for i .Nothing is working. My IDE tells me that there's no such property in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could iterate over `Object.entries(page)` and where value of string `''` length is zero or it is `undefined`, we change the key value to `null`.

```js
  setNulls(page: any) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(page)) {
      if (value === undefined || String(value).length === 0) {
        page[key] = null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-loop-object-keys-and-display-in-table-usin-l7pq7k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, getting a 7053 error too.
 Here's the french version : L'élément a implicitement un type 'any', car l'expression de type 'string' ne peut pas être utilisée pour indexer le type 'Page'.
  Aucune signature d'index avec un paramètre de type 'string' n'a été localisée sur le type 'Page'.ts(7053)
Basically it says that string cannot be used to index 'Page'

Comment: not sure about that.

Comment: We can get rid of the TS error by checking it against a String explicitly `if (value === undefined || String(value).length === 0)`

Comment: It seems to be working, thanks a lot ! I just added the type in parameters like this 

setNulls(page: any) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(page)) {
      if (value === undefined || String(value).length === 0) {
        page[key] = null;
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Oh yeah, good catch. Add the type as `Page`. `setNulls(page: Page)` since you have defined the type.

Comment: Setting the type to Page (setNulls(page: Page)) doesn't work here. I get the same ts.7053 error. Probably because some fields are defined as strings in models.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can loop object like this

```
for (const key of Object.keys(this.page)) {
    if (this.page[key] === undefined || this.page[key] === ''){
        (<any>this.page)[key] = null;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but i get an error like this :

Element implicitly has 'any' type, because 'string' type cannot be used to index 'Page' type. No index signature was located on type 'Page'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below :-

```
if (page) {
  Object.keys(page).forEach((key) => {
    if (page[key] === undefined || page[key] === '') {
       page[key] = null;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, getting a 7053 error too.

Comment: 7053 error? whats that

Comment: Something like this : TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string"' can't be used to index type 'Page'.
  Property 'string' does not exist on type 'Page'.